# How can I update my Microsoft Store application description?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-store-apps

I have logged into the Partner Center and cannot find a method to update the description for my app. Is this something that is done in the Partner Center or is this something that needs to be done during packaging within Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Log in to the Microsoft Partner Centre
2. Find your app
3. Click on "Update" from the "Application Overview" tab
4. Go to "Store Listings"
5. Click on "add/remove languages"
6. Click on the language you would like to update such as "English (United States)"
7. Update your description